# Why am I getting an ECONNREFUSED error when I try to insert a row into my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pm2

I want to use a process manager (pm2) in order to keep my Node.js running even when my terminal is closed. However, it doesn't seem like I can use `mysql.createConnection` with it anymore and I have been told that I need to use `mysql.createPool` instead.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to work and I keep getting an ECONNREFUSED error. Here is the error message in its entirety:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at /Users/btang/NodeJS/server.js:124:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/btang/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

And here is the code I have written so far:

```
const express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: process.env.MYSQL_CONLIM,
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DBNAME
});

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var context = {};
    pool.query("INSERT INTO Survey (ParticipantID) VALUES ?", [req.query.c], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
        res.render('home', context);
    });
});

app.listen(3001,()=>console.log("Port 3001"));
```

I couldn't find my resources to try to find the proper way to write an INSERT query using pool connection so I just "Frankenstein"-ed it.

If there are any good resources for me to look at, can you also point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The connection was refused (ECONNREFUSED) so there's no port 3306 listening on IP 127.0.0.1. It's either mysql not running or may be a firewall issue. Check listening port on your os

Comment: If I'm using AWS MySQL, will I still see it running on one of my ports?

Comment: No, it's running on a remote host in that case.